# Count Files in a TeamDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, count, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create a script to count the files in a TeamDrive. Does anyone have a simple codeexample for me. This is my current code - it runs but does not count files.

```js
function myTeamDrives() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.clear();
  var folders = Drive.Teamdrives.list({maxResults:100});
  var row = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length ; i++) {
    var folder = folders.items[i];
    var fID = folders.items[i].getId();

    var xx = DriveApp.getFolderById(fID).getFiles();
    var anzF = 0
    
    while (xx.hasNext()) {
      var file = xx.next();
      anzF = anzF + 1
    }    
        
    row = row + 1 
    ss.getRange(row, 1).setValue(folder.name);
    ss.getRange(row, 2).setValue(anzF);
    ss.getRange(row, 3).setValue(fID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to count all files in subfolders as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder= folder || DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    n++;
  }
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
}
```

To test it try this:

```
var n=0;//global

function testgetFnf() {
  n=0;
  getFnF();
  Logger.log(n);
}
```

You can recover the number of files by viewing logs

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for my late answer. Exactly what I need. It works perfect. Thanks, Thanks, Thanks